# Is it possible to run a Magento 2 application without the installation?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Let's say I can not successfully run the Magento 2 installation by some reasons.
And my friend has all the code and setup of a Magento 2 apps running normally in his PC
Then he zip the whole file and send to me including all needed information such as whole database file and settings.

Let's say I don't have any different settings of my friend(PHP,apache or Mysql), Is it possible to run a Magento 2 application without the installation?

Comment: Yes - it is very common to move websites from one server to another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make sure you have all the required files from his environment. Especially the app/etc/env.php file which has all the details related with DB connection and crypt key which is also important.